# Como liberar memoria en java en un hilo

Tags: java, netbeans, hilos, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Java, esta debe traspasar información de una base de datos a otra en cierto intervalo de tiempo.
Actualmente funciona con un ciclo infinito dentro de un hilo, porque el usuario necesita abrir la aplicación y que esta no pare de funcionar en todo el día.
Sucede que mientras está corriendo, la aplicación acumula mucha memoria, que después aparece el mensaje

```
[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]
```

Si no me equivoco la memoria se libera cuando el ciclo termina, pero en este caso es infinito, que se puede hacer?

Aquí está la clase

```
package Model;

import Control.Controller;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Ciclo implements Runnable {

Controller myController;
private boolean iterar;
private String web_service;
private String token;
private String pc;
private int segundos = 10000;

public void setSegundos(int segundos){
    this.segundos = segundos;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (iterar) {
        try {


            if (!myController.getConexionWebService(web_service, token, pc)){
            } else if (!myController.getConexionMysql()){
            } else if (!myController.getJsonFileExist()){
            }else{

                myController.proceso1();

            }

            if (!myController.getConexionWebService(web_service, token, pc)){
            } else if (!myController.getConexionMysql()){
            } else if (!myController.getJsonFileExist()){
            }else{

                myController.proceso2();

            }
            sleep(segundos);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ciclo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            myController.setWriteError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    myController.setReanudarTrue();
    return;
}

public void setController(Controller myController) {
    this.myController = myController;
}

public void iniciar(String web_service, String token, String pc) {
    this.web_service = web_service;
    this.token = token;
    this.pc = pc;
    iterar = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void pausar() {
    iterar = false;
}

public void reanudar() {
    iterar = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}



}
```

Comment: Y que fue de tu problema? pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puede ser es la pérdida de memoria en uno de tus procesos causado por que no cierras un recurso, ya sea un PreparedStatement, ResultSet, sql.Connection, http.Connection entre tantas cosas que puedes tener como pérdida de memoria.

También puede que estes recibiendo un dato demasiado pesado de la base de datos, o del webservice y quieras pasarlo a byte array, por lo que te recomiendo uses Stream para los blobs, o hasta para los strings demasiado grandes.

Te recomiendo usar un profile de la máquina virtual para ver que objeto es el que se está acumulando, así puedas darnos más información.

http://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Si usas Java 7 o superior utiliza los try-catch-resources https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero añadir que los recursos no son necesariamente la única forma de no liberar memoria. Por ejemplo igual tiene una estructura estática demasiado compleja (un `List` de objetos pesados que nunca elimina y cosas así).